# "Page Will Not Display" error with new site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online

Just installed SharePoint 2016. We created a new web app and a new site collection. Upon navigating to the new site collection, we are faced with a "Page Cannot be Displayed" error.

We have tried:

- Resetting ISS
- Updating User Policy
- Trying to access /_Layouts/15/settings.aspx and /_Layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx with no success
- Trying to upload the site within SP Designer 2013 without success
- Removing host header
- It is not configured to use SSL

Nothing has worked so far, any other suggestions?

Comment: check ULS files to find more information about this error. The default path of ULS log file is: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS. And, create a new site collection, check if the new one could work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the logs. We did try multiple site collections with no resolution, unfortunately.

Comment: have you checked ULS log files to find the related error message? If yes, please provide it

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem with my Enterprise Search Centre.

- Check your DNS is set up correctly
- Check your hosts file for bad /old
  entries
- Check the Bindings and host name are set up correctly in IIS
- Check the site and application pool are started in IIS
- Ping the web app to see if it gets a response
- Set up a new site collection in the same Web App to ensure
  the web application is working
- Check Super User and Super Reader account permissions on the Web Application

I made all the same checks, found that DNS was not set up for the url, once I set it up and still the same error I simply deleted the site collection and created it again and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. That's what we keep getting hung up on - we shouldn't have to set up DNS yet because we are only accessing the site on the server, correct?

Comment: If you have not set up DNS you will need to add a hosts file entry for the URL if it is not the same as the server name to point to itself (localhost = 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue is still occurring. I'll keep doing some research, thanks for your help!